# Delete a carriage return in a txt file

Tags: c#, file, line

I create a program that uses a txt file that looks like this:

```
01/11 09:56,yeo,no,110222100,no
01/11 09:55,Test,Test2,110222100,Test2
01/11 09:52,Jack,Jean,112222100,Jean
31/10 23:17,Rayane,Jean,111220000,Rayane
```

I would then like a line in this file to delete it, so I use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lignes.Count; i++)
{
    string ligne = lignes[i];
    List<string> element = ligne.Split(',').ToList();

    if (element.Contains(selectionDate[1])) //Ici on à les éléments de la ligne séléctionner
    {
        string ligneAr = null;
        lignes[i] = ligneAr;
        File.WriteAllLines(path, lignes);
    }
}
```

But, when I use this code, this is what happens in the txt file:

```
01/11 09:56,yeo,no,110222100,no
01/11 09:55,Test,Test2,110222100,Test2
01/11 09:52,Jack,Jean,112222100,Jean
31/10 23:17,Rayane,Jean,111220000,Rayane
// Empty line
31/10 22:30,Rayane,André,122120101,Rayane
```

There's a hole in the text instead.
How can I delete this hole?
The code that allows you to create it is in the if()

Thank you.

Comment: what value available in `selectionDate[1]`, why are you splitting `ligne`

Comment: The line "File.WriteAllLines(path, lignes)" is in the wrong place in the code.

Comment: @RayaneStaszewski the code *created* the hole by setting that line to a `null` instead of removing it

Comment: You don't need to create a list of the lines either, if you intend to exclude one of them. You can use `var newLines=lines.Where(l=>!l.StartsWith(someString)); File.WriteAllLinex(path,newLines);`. This avoids creating a temporary list just to hold the values - `newLines` is an IEnumerable<T> that's only enumerated when writing out the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hole which you mentioned in your question is added due to assigning `null` to `lignes[i]` i.e `lignes[i] = ligneAr;`. `File.WriteAllLines()` inside for loop, is also wrong place to update your file.

No need to split your string `lignes[i]`, you can just use `.Where()` clause with required condition to get filtered result and write it to the file.

Something like,

```
var result = lignes.Where(ligne => !ligne.Contains(selectionDate[1]));
File.WriteAllLines(path, result);
```

Comment: Okay, it's noted.